# set default vim as editor instead macvim

Tags: macos, vim

i've installed macVim on mojave, a collegue added it as alias in `.zshrc` and also added an alias for it as "vim". Now, i want to change it with another alias like mvim, so i could use both the editor; so i `unalias vim`, removed the alias in `.zshrc` but i still see the new vim editor when i try to use vim command. where is the file that tell osx to open macVim instead vim? i've also tryed to uninstall macVim, but i still se the new editor.
Sorry i'm new in osx ,i'm trying to be clear.
Thanks

Comment: try a fresh installation by running brew install vim

Comment: if i do which vim it says : /usr/bin/vim so looks like its the original vim, but i see the vim welcome massage that i didn't saw previously

Comment: @AneesKodappana ok it works, but just to understand, if i want to add an alias, i've to alias vim=/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim and also edit the .zshrc? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use Vim if you have MacVim? MacVim is almost entirely backward-compatible - I haven't found a significant difference in many years of use - and provides a superior experience on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if your "vim" is aliased you can enter in your Terminal:

```
type vim
```

To find out where your alias is set:

```
grep -s "alias" ~/.* | grep -i "vim"
```

---

As you said, you may add in your .zshrc:

```
alias mvim=/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
```

then to refresh the changes:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: perfect, but i've also to edit the .zshrc? and add alias vim=/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim also there? becouse i've did it in shell and it work, but in the .zshrc file there i didn't add it

Comment: i can see the alias by typing alias in shell but still didn't edited the .zshrc file

Comment: @ClaudioBiselli If you do the alias command in the shell, it won't be permanent: try to open a new terminal window, and it won't work. If you want your alias to be permanent, then you have to edit your .zshrc